Ag-grid autoheight and fixed header
I am displaying a grid with domLayout: 'autoheight' and I need a fixed header on top.
With the querySelector I select the header and add it a fixed position.
const agheader: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('.ag-header')!;
agheader!.style.position = 'fixed';
agheader!.style.top = '0';
agheader!.style.zIndex = '100';

The header is placed correctly on top.
When I scroll horizontally the header is aligned with the body.

Now i only add a container to the ag grid width a padding of 2rem
  <div style="padding: 2rem">
    <div>
      <ag-grid-angular
        class="ag-theme-quartz"
        style="height: 500px;"
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
        [rowData]="rowData"
        (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
      />
    </div>
  </div>

I scroll horizontally again the table from the start

the header and the body are not aligned but I have just added a padding.
Full repro here https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cxeq2u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
